# Stackdriver agent installation failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

I am trying to install Stackdriver Agent. I am using the Google cloud instance (os Ubuntu) and followed the instruction given at google cloud docs for monitoring. Here, are the logs from my server console.

```
root@instance-1:~/opt# sudo bash stack-install.sh --write-gcm
Installing agents for Debian or Ubuntu.
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
OK
Hit:1 http://asia-east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:2 http://asia-east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates     InRelease
Get:3 http://asia-east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports     InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Hit:5 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (111 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package stackdriver-agent
Installation failed.
root@instance-1:~/opt#
```

Comment: You can read the script source (or get it from https://repo.stackdriver.com/stack-install.sh). That might help you to debug it. Guessing that https://repo.stackdriver.com/yakkety.list does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of documented OSs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/#supported_operating_systems), the following are supported at present:

- LTS 12.04 "Precise"
- LTS 14.04 "Trusty"
- LTS 16.04 "Xenial"

And it appears that only LTS releases are supported.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to type this:

```
sudo apt-cache madison stackdriver-agent
```

To show the list of available versions of the agent in order to select which version to install.

**Results:**

> stackdriver-agent | 6.0.2-1.bionic |
>   http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
>   google-cloud-monitoring-bionic-all/main amd64 Packages
>
> stackdriver-agent | 6.0.1-1.bionic |
>   http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
>   google-cloud-monitoring-bionic-all/main amd64 Packages
>
> stackdriver-agent | 6.0.0-1.bionic |
>   http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
>   google-cloud-monitoring-bionic-all/main amd64 Packages
>
> stackdriver-agent | 5.5.2-1002.bionic |
>   http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
>   google-cloud-monitoring-bionic-all/main amd64 Packages
>
> stackdriver-agent | 5.5.2-1001.bionic |
>   http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt
>   google-cloud-monitoring-bionic-all/main amd64 Packages

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install -y 'stackdriver-agent=[MAJOR_VERSION].*'
```

**For example**, to pin to the 6.0.2-1 bionic of the agent, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y 'stackdriver-agent=6.0.2-1.bionic*'
```